# How to access device private information via device name in a Linux kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

I have a simple device driver and want to access the `struct device *` of a different device. How can I do this via the Linux kernel API using only the name of the device? I know there are API calls like `of_find_node_by_phandle()` but the device is not accessible from the device tree. All I know is the name of the device.

`driver_find_device_by_name()` is almost what I'm looking for, but I would need a `struct device_driver *` which I don't have:

```
dev = driver_find_device_by_name(drv, "device-name");
```

Comment: As far as I understand from the code, Linux kernel simply has **no global list of devices**. Each **bus** (`struct bus_type`) maintains its own list of devices, so by knowing a bus you could find a device by name. But a bus itself cannot be searched for by name: there is no list of buses. A device driver can also be searched by name.. but only within a bus the driver belongs to.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the hint. I found the function `struct device_driver *driver_find(const char *name, struct bus_type *bus)` which might do the trick. How do I find the `bus_type` of the desired device?

Comment: "How do I find the bus_type of the desired device?" - As far as I understand, there is no generic mechanism for that. If you have some considerations about the *kind* of the desired device, then you may find the code which registers it. But most likely given code declares an object of type `struct bus_type` as **static**, and provides no way for outside code for get this object. Only if you create a device (or driver) for the **same bus**, then you could extract bus from the field `bus` of your device structure.

Comment: You don't need to know driver, if you know the bus of the device. There are respective methods to match — `bus_find_device_by_name()` or so. (FYI, @Tsyvarev)

Comment: @0andriy: Hmm, may be my first comment is not so clear, but it describes exactly that way (without naming a function): "by knowing a bus you could find a device by name". Approach with the driver is just an *alternative*.